# Jquery name selector text blur

Tags: jquery

I have some text boxes with names:

```
 1. txt_provider_quote_1
 2. txt_provider_quote_2
 3. txt_provider_quote_3

 4. txt_provider_quote_dlg_1
 5. txt_provider_quote_dlg_2
 6. txt_provider_quote_dlg_3
```

And a blur function:

```
$('input[name^=txt_provider_quote_]').blur(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

The blur is executing for all 6 textbox.
I want it to execute only for first 3 textbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to filter out the elements you don't want from the collection. Try:

```
$('input[name^=txt_provider_quote_]').not('input[name^=txt_provider_quote_dlg]').blur(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

instead.

Comment: It works as expected, however not as readable and efficient as mine. +1 for your answer @adrian-wragg

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class attribute to affected inputs like:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_provider_quote_1" class="blur_affected">
<input type="text" name="txt_provider_quote_2" class="blur_affected">
<input type="text" name="txt_provider_quote_3" class="blur_affected">
```

Omit this class in other inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_provider_quote_dlg_1">
<input type="text" name="txt_provider_quote_dlg_2">
<input type="text" name="txt_provider_quote_dlg_3">
```

And now jQuery:

```
$('input.blur_affected').blur(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: I don't no. of text fields in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    $('input[name^=txt_provider_quote_]').not('input[name^=txt_provider_quote_dlg]').blur(function(){
       alert("hi");
    });
```

Here is [demo](http://jsbin.com/arudof/1/edit)

Comment: The comma serves as an `AND`. I think `$('input[name^=txt_provider_quote_]:not([name^=txt_provider_quote_dlg_])')` will do as intended. Alternatively `$('input[name^=txt_provider_quote_]').not('[name^=txt_provider_quote_dlg_]')`